# I want to create a connection with a browser and want to store all the upcoming requests in a file

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, automation, python-requests

There is a website on which if i make a connection on browser it my browser constantly keep on sending new requests to the website endpoints but these end points are dynamic. So i want to create a python program which will create a connection with the website and will store the all new made request urls in a file ? How to do it in python?
I am trying something like

```
import requests
import time

url = "https://example.com/asdd"

while True:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
            for line in response.text.splitlines():
                if line.endswith(".jpg"):
                    f.write(line)
    else:
        print("Failed")
    time.sleep(20)
```

I may be very very wrong but can you point me the right direction.

Comment: This looks aproximately correct. Did you try running it? Did  you get any good output, any output and/or just error messages. You'll need to update your question with that sort of information for readerrs to be able to help you. **Don't put those details in comments!** Good luck.

Comment: What's the site? [If it's not a site you can share] can you explain more about how the site behaves and is structured?  What results are you getting in `file.txt` and what do you not like about it?